# jquery toggle menu abnormalities

Tags: drop-down-menu, jquery

I have two dropdown hidden menus ie menu A and menu B that shows up when you click on link A and B respectively and vice versa and also disappears when u click anywhere in the body. The problem I have is when I click on link B whilst link A is still activated, menu A stays open instead of closing and this leads to many complications. Dunno what I am doing wrong.

you can view the code at [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qwuhZ/7/)

or here is the code am using;

html;

```
<ul>
<li id="tabs" class="notification">
<a>Click for Notification</a>
<div id="notification">
<h3>Your Notifications</h3>
<p>Notification #1</p>
<p>Notification #2</p>
<p>Notification #3</p>
<p>Notification #4</p>
<p>Notification #5</p>
<p>Notification #6</p>
</div>
</li>


<li id="tabs" class="latest">
<a>Click for Latest News</a>
<div id="latest">
<h3>Your Latest News</h3>
<p>News #1</p>
<p>News #2</p>
<p>News #3</p>
<p>Notification #4</p>
<p>News #5</p>
<p>News #6</p>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

jquery;

```
$(function() {
            $("li#tabs.notification a").click(function(e) {
                $("#notification").toggle().addClass("active");
                $('li#tabs a').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                e.stopPropagation();
            });

            $(document).click(function(e) {
                $('#notification').hide().removeClass('active');
                $('li#tabs a').removeClass('selected');
            });

            $("#notification").click(function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        });


$(function() {
            $("li#tabs.latest a").click(function(e) {
                $("#latest").toggle().toggleClass("active");
                $('li#tabs a').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                e.stopPropagation();
            });

            $(document).click(function(e) {
                $('#latest').hide().removeClass('active');
                $('li#tabs a').removeClass('selected');
            });

            $("#latest").click(function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        });
```

Comment: <div> cannot be placed outside of the <li> tags. This is invalid markup.

Comment: id attribute must be unique on the page, do not use it twice: <li id="tabs"..., use class instead,e.g. on parent element <ul class="tabs">, the css selector will be then '.tabs li'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is about displaying and hiding correct content.

```
$(function() {
        $("li#tabs.notification a").click(function(e) {
            $("#notification").toggle().toggleClass("active");
            $('#latest').hide();
            $('#notification').show();  
            $('li#tabs a').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

        $(document).click(function(e) {
            $('#notification').hide().removeClass('active');
            $('#latest').hide();              
            $('li#tabs a').removeClass('selected');
        });

        $("#notification").click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });


    $(function() {
        $("li#tabs.latest a").click(function(e) {
            $("#latest").toggle().toggleClass("active");
            $('#notification').hide();
            $('#latest').show();
            $('li#tabs a').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

        $(document).click(function(e) {
            $('#latest').hide().removeClass('active');
            $('li#tabs a').removeClass('selected');
        });

        $("#latest").click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
```

I really suggest re-thinking the solution because if you get lots of tabs then you will end up having huge amount of duplicate code.

For example: when clicking the title it would display elements inside it and hide all the other elements. Then it would not have to know what is the Id of the `div` like it is now doing with `#notification` and `#latest`

Comment: i agree with you @Tx3...fortunately i need it for only two tabs but do you have any suggestions?

Comment: tweaked your script a little bit man! Working like a charm now. The only delimma is what you raised...having several tabs but it's cool for now. http://jsfiddle.net/qwuhZ/8/